# Docker for windows hangs while trying to see settings

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have installed Docker desktop for Windows (docker 19.0.3 on windows 10). While I go to settings it hangs with status updating and never comes back.

[image]

I have tried uninstalling and installing but doesnt help.
Hyper-V and Container features are switched on in windows 10.
Kindly help me in knowing what exactly might be wrong with this ?

Comment: I am having the same issue.. It was running fine up until a few daya ago... Maybe an MS or Docker update issue??

Comment: Troubleshoot -> Clean / Purge data worked for me. I just installed Docker Desktop today via VS2019 on Windows 10 and experienced this same issue. Since I have not even started using Docker yet using Purge data was no issue for me. Yeah, I would certainly not of used it had I already been using Docker for some time. I whole heartedly agree with @chronic

Answer (score 27):

The only way I could fix this was by opening a powershell and switching daemons:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCLI.exe' -SwitchDaemon
```

Comment: Congrats! You save my day

Comment: The problem is that you must do this every time you want to use Docker Desktop. And today I can't see the link to my Ubuntu installation. Docker on Windows is a real pain.

Comment: This i started facing after recent update came. But this command really worked, Thanks a lot. Could you please add little detail on what this command actually does and why we need to do this ?

Comment: That solution worked for me. What causes this? I had a running daemon, what daemon am I switching to?

Comment: @Woodsman My understanding is that there is a linux based one (doesn't require vmm) and windows based one and whilst Microsoft seems to play like you can do everything with the linux one now experience tells me it doesn't work like that yet.  I'm guessing if you had the issue I did then you are switching to the windows daemon (that requires vmm to be running).

Comment: This solution worked for me. But note, I could not see my docker images after running the switch command the first time. After repeating this command again, I could see my old docker images. As @MikeCheel mentioned, running this command may have changed the daemon to Windows one and in my case it had no docker images and running this command the second time switches it back to the Linux one and I could see my previous docker images.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm still stuck with infinite loading loop

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this same problem on Windows 10, through troubleshooting I discovered the ***WampServer had some kind of conflict with Docker*** (possibly to do with ports). I know not everyone who experiences this hanging phenomenon is using WampServer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by "Reset to factory defaults".

Answer (score -1):

For me, only this worked: **Troubleshoot** -> **Clean / Purge data**

@Eric Hepperle - in current docker version there is selection tooltip which data set(s) you want to delete.

Answer (score -2):

Running Docker Desktop as Administrator you can access to settings. Many days to find it :-(

Answer (score -2):

For me it helped to use **Clean / Purge data** from the troubleshooting menu. The menu is accesible by right clicking on the docker tray symbol -> Troubleshooting.

Comment: This advice did not help and it destroyed all my data sets! It seems "Purge Data" could mean `remove leftover and cached queries or tables`, but it doesn't. It means "Delete all Data". They could have just said that.

Comment: The documentation tells you what will be deleted: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#troubleshoot. "Clean / Purge data: Select this option to delete container and image data. Choose whether you’d like to delete data from Hyper-V, WSL 2, or Windows Containers and then click Delete to confirm."

Comment: This type of answer is why the whole study of "User Experience" came about. While it is good that docker documentation details what exactly will happen, it is not that consumable to normal humans. To make it more useful you add something like this `"Warning: Choosing this option will DELETE ALL YOUR DATA and ALL YOUR CONTAINERS. Are you sure you want to continue?"`

Comment: How about you learn to use your tools before using it in production and follow the advice of a stranger from the internet? No matter how many warning signs are attached to something, there will always be this person that has the skill to ignore them. Also: No backup no sorry.